# problema al convertir float a string c#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando realizar una conversión simple de **float** a **string** para mostrar unos datos en unos `label`, el problema es que al realizar la conversión no me reconoce el punto decimal y me muestra el dato con la operación realizada pero sin la coma o el punto:

X se define mediante el rango seleccionado en un `comboBox` en el caso del ejemplo abajo x = 1:

```
 public float x;

private void escalarX()
        {
            if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "0-5")
            {
                x = 818.8f;
            }

            else if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "0-10")
            {
                x = 409.4f;

            }
          
            else if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "0-50")
            {

                x = 81.88f;

            }
            else if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "0-100")
            {

                x = 40.94f;

            }
            else if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "REAL")
            {

                x = 1;

            }
            else
            {

                x = 0;

            }
        }
```

Después se realiza la operación y muestro los datos de la siguiente manera:

```
 private void escalarMeasurements()
        {
            float MeasurementRango1 = float.Parse(lbRealData1.Text) * x;
            float MeasurementRango2 = float.Parse(lbRealData2.Text) * x;
            float MeasurementRango3 = float.Parse(lbRealData3.Text) * x;
            float MeasurementRango4 = float.Parse(lbRealData4.Text) * x;
            float MeasurementRango5 = float.Parse(lbRealData5.Text) * x;
            float MeasurementRango6 = float.Parse(lbRealData6.Text) * x;
            float MeasurementRango7 = float.Parse(lbRealData7.Text) * x;
            float MeasurementRango8 = float.Parse(lbRealData8.Text) * x;


            lbRangoData1.Text = MeasurementRango1.ToString();
            lbRangoData2.Text = MeasurementRango2.ToString();
            lbRangoData3.Text = MeasurementRango3.ToString();
            lbRangoData4.Text = MeasurementRango4.ToString();
            lbRangoData5.Text = MeasurementRango5.ToString();
            lbRangoData6.Text = MeasurementRango6.ToString();
            lbRangoData7.Text = MeasurementRango7.ToString();
            lbRangoData8.Text = MeasurementRango8.ToString();

        }
```

Pero el resultado es la operación pero sin el punto que separa los decimales:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si convierto a float el resultado de la operación mediante

```
MeasurementRangoX.ToString("F")
```

o

```
MeasurementRangoX.ToString("N2")
```

El resultado obtenido es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que puedo deducir que el resultado incorrecto al parsear es el primero:

```
 float MeasurementRango1 = float.Parse(lbRealData1.Text) * x;
```

¿Cómo puedo parsear correctamente lbRealData1.Text? Este dato también lo puedo obtener mediante un array de strings string[] values;

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
string month = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();

if (month.Length < 2)
{
month = "0" + month;
}

Debug.WriteLine(month);

String last = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"D:\Vistachrom\#21461120\Trend\\" + year + "\\" + month + "\\" + year + "" + month + "_BTX-15MN_Result_airTOXIC-STD.Asc").Last();

Debug.WriteLine(last);

string[] values = last.Split('\t');

lbFecha.Text = values[0];
lbVolumen.Text = values[1];
lbBenzeno.Text = values[2];
lbCyclohexano.Text = values[3];
lbTolueno.Text = values[4];
lbEthylbenzeno.Text = values[5];
lbMypxylelenos.Text = values[6];
lbStyreno.Text = values[7];
lbOxyleno.Text = values[8];
```

El cual lee de un fichero que tiene el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es la columna que debemos mirar? Qué dato traen esos float? Recuerda que sólo tú conoces el contexto completo...

Comment: Es la columna ESCALA, se obtiene de multiplicar la columna REAL * X (en este caso 1)

Comment: Cómo está definido `x`?

Comment: Quiza `lblRangoDataX.Text = MeasurementRangoX.ToString("F");` te ayude.

Comment: Si quieres fijar el número de decimales también te puede ir bien `MeasurementRangoX.ToString("N2")`  (2 decimales es este ejemplo)

Comment: MeasurementRangoX.ToString("N2") Y MeasurementRangoX.ToString("F") funcionan correctamente al pasar el resultado obtenido a string para mostrarlo en el label, el problema que es por donde viene todo que me acabo de dar cuenta es que los datos de la columna REAL se obtienen de un fichero, y al pasarlos float se pierde el . y los valores decimales pasan a ser enteros, edito la pregunta para que lo veais. Gracias.

Comment: @Alfabravo x se define de la siguiente manera: public float x; y se asigna el valor asi:  if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "0-5")
            {
                x = 818.8f;
            }

            else if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "0-10")
            {
                x = 409.4f;

            } etc... en este caso  else if (cbRango.SelectedItem.ToString() == "REAL")
            {

                x = 1;

            }

Comment: Como podrás ver, no tiene mucha utilidad poner código en los comentarios. Edita tu pregunta las veces que haga falta para añadir la información necesaria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado indicando el tipo de cultura `en-US` para que reconozca el punto como separador de los valores decimales en vez de la coma:

```
private void escalarMeasurements()
{
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

        float MeasurementRango1 = float.Parse(lbRealData1.Text, culture) * x;
        float MeasurementRango2 = float.Parse(lbRealData2.Text, culture) * x;
        float MeasurementRango3 = float.Parse(lbRealData3.Text, culture) * x;
        float MeasurementRango4 = float.Parse(lbRealData4.Text, culture) * x;
        float MeasurementRango5 = float.Parse(lbRealData5.Text, culture) * x;
        float MeasurementRango6 = float.Parse(lbRealData6.Text, culture) * x;
        float MeasurementRango7 = float.Parse(lbRealData7.Text, culture) * x;
        float MeasurementRango8 = float.Parse(lbRealData8.Text, culture) * x;


        lbRangoData1.Text = MeasurementRango1.ToString("N2", culture);
        lbRangoData2.Text = MeasurementRango2.ToString("N2", culture);
        lbRangoData3.Text = MeasurementRango3.ToString("N2", culture);
        lbRangoData4.Text = MeasurementRango4.ToString("N2", culture);
        lbRangoData5.Text = MeasurementRango5.ToString("N2", culture);
        lbRangoData6.Text = MeasurementRango6.ToString("N2", culture);
        lbRangoData7.Text = MeasurementRango7.ToString("N2", culture);
        lbRangoData8.Text = MeasurementRango8.ToString("N2", culture);



 }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]